# Problem passing value from Jsp to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a variable from the jsp part that i'd like to use in the javascript (in this case an address i need to send to an API through javascript).

For example instead of being already written in the code (5th avenue in my example), i'd like to replace the query by a variable I get from the request (in jsp).

In other words i'd like this:

`$.ajax({url: 'http://api.blabla.com',data: {access_key: 'MYAPIKEY',query: '5th avenue' ,limit: 1} }).done(function(data)`

To be like that:

`$.ajax({url: 'http://api.blabla.com',data: {access_key: 'MYAPIKEY',query: variablefromJsp ,limit: 1} }).done(function(data)`

[JSP screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8HOn.png)

[Javascript Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVYhR.png)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Use the variable name where you are capturing the value - `inJavascriptvalue`

Comment: yes but should I write like this? data: {access_key: 'MYAPIKEY',query: inJavascriptvalue,limit: 1} }).done(function(data)

Comment: Did it work? Also, this post is probably going to be flagged as a "simple typographical error" and closed. Check out the site's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more info on what SO looks for in good questions and answers.